# open set and cardinality

Tags: general-topology

I've learnt Set Theory, but I didn't learn Topology and Measure Theory. I met a term "open set" today. According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set),

> An open set is an abstract concept generalizing the idea of an open interval in the real line.

I understand how a set could be open in terms of intervals on a real number line. But I don't know how a set like {1,3,4} (a finite set) could be open.

It seems to me that all finite sets are not open. And since the set of all natural numbers "has" an element "infinity", it is also open. Hence I guess an open set has cardinality no smaller than Aleph null.

Are my intuitions correct? Thanks

Comment: I think you should read and understand the definition of a open set.

Comment: Openness does not make sense out of context. Given a set $X$, you can define when a collection $T$ of subsets of $X$ forms a *topology* on $X$. If $X$ is a set, $T$ is a topology on $X$, and $O\subseteq X$, then (and only then) it makes sense to ask whether $O$ is open. This simply means that $O\in T$. If we did not have $X$ and $T$, the question would be meaningless. The axioms of a topology are designed to abstract basic properties of unions of open intervals in the real line, but are general enough that it is indeed possible to have topologies $T$ where some finite non-empty sets are open.

Comment: The set of natural numbers doesn't "have" an element "infinity".  And I'm afraid this is not how intuition in mathematics works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topology is an abstract term. Like set. $\{0,1,2\}$ is a set, and also $\Bbb N$ is a set, and also $\{\Bbb N\}$ is a set. Sets don't necessarily have to be finite, or sets of natural numbers, or have numbers as elements. Sets are just sets.

Similarly a topology on a set $X$ is just a collection of subsets of $X$ which satisfy some properties:

1. $\varnothing$ and $X$ are in the collection;
2. If for all $i\in I$, $A_i$ are in this collection, so must be $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$; and
3. If $A,B$ are in the collection, so are $A\cap B$.

Then this collection is called "a topology" and sets which are in this collection are called *open*. These properties are true for the open sets on $\Bbb R$, but there are other properties true there, which we didn't require from "a topology". Those additional properties may have names, or not.

But for a collection $\tau$ to be a topology on a set $X$, it just has to satisfy the three conditions above. Now note that taking *all* the subsets of a set $X$ will necessarily satisfy these properties. Therefore by taking *all* the subsets of $\Bbb R$ we obtain a topology on $\Bbb R$ where every set is open (because every subset of $\Bbb R$ is in this topology). In particular $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Do you mean that since $\{1,2,3\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the set is *open* under the definition of "open" in your post? Hence, it seems the definition is not quite similar to what we say an interval is "open". Right?

Comment: Yes. Open intervals are open in the standard topology.